# Vuex Store for Multistep Form

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I want to build a multistep form application in vue. The form schema is being pulled in as a json and a form is generated according to the definitions in there. I am using vue.js as a store.
Rendering the form is no problem as the component tree
`Form 1--*> Step 1--*> Question 1--1>FormComponent`
works.

As I want to dynamically use a model in the formcomponent referring to a different place in the store which should be prepped by the same schema mentionned above, I looked for tutorials and found this one https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/how-to-structure-a-complex-vuex-store/

I thought I'd found the solution by using models for my store, but I can't seem to get it to work. I can't find the answer in tutorials & docs.
Where can I find further guidance or council?

Thankyou

Comment: Read this? https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

Comment: This any use? https://medium.com/engineering-samlino/building-a-multi-step-form-with-vue-2bc861447c4a